# How to turn a simple 1-dimensional array into an HTML table using Handlebars.js?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

This seems like it should be simple but I'm having one hell of a time with it.

I have an array with some names in it: var foobar = ["John Doe", "Jane Doe", "Mike Doe"];

I then want to form a simple HTML table using Handlebars.js (yes I want to include the down arrow between each name):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>John Doe</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&darr;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jane Doe</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&darr;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mike Doe</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

However, I cannot find a way to even reference foobar in my template.hdbs. {{#foobar}} does not work. I'm reading about helpers but find them extremely confusing and there's not a lot of examples of simple operations like this.

I know. I'm a moron.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a template that looks like this:

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <table>
        {{#each this}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{.}}</td>
            </tr>
            {{#unless @last}}
                <tr>
                     <td>&darr;</td>
                </tr>
            {{/unless}}
        {{/each}}
    </table>
</script>
```

You will pass `foobar` to the template method returned from `Handlebars.compile`. So `foobar` will be referenced from within the template as `this`, and each iteration can be referenced with a `.`.  I am using jQuery to get the template source HTML and to append our result to the page:

```
var foobar = ["John Doe", "Jane Doe", "Mike Doe"];
var source = $('#template').html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
$('body').append(template(foobar));
```

Comment: You're great. Thank you. I can't upvote because I don't have enough reputation or whatever.